# What does this "what is" mean?

Tags: grammar

> To comprehend **what is**, this is the task of philosophy, because **what is**, is reason.
>   [Source](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=pbVfkl79HY0C&pg=PA428&lpg=PA428&dq=Whatever%20happens,%20every%20individual%20is%20a%20child%20of%20his%20time;%20so%20philosophy%20too%20is%20its%20own%20time%20apprehended%20in%20thoughts.%20It%20is%20just%20as%20absurd%20to%20fancy%20that%20a%20philosophy%20can%20transcend%20its%20contemporary%20world%20as%20it%20is%20to%20fancy%20that%20an%20individual%20can%20overleap%20his%20own%20age,%20jump%20over%20Rhodes.%22&source=bl&ots=fGu3vGG5HE&sig=AvuXkAEGF6hsLE-wiW93jnhotnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w9aDU5LzMc3y8QW6o4KoDw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Whatever%20happens,%20every%20individual%20is%20a%20child%20of%20his%20time;%20so%20philosophy%20too%20is%20its%20own%20time%20apprehended%20in%20thoughts.%20It%20is%20just%20as%20absurd%20to%20fancy%20that%20a%20philosophy%20can%20transcend%20its%20contemporary%20world%20as%20it%20is%20to%20fancy%20that%20an%20individual%20can%20overleap%20his%20own%20age,%20jump%20over%20Rhodes.%22&f=false)

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One meaning of 'be' (are/am/is/were/was) is 'exist'. In Shakespeare's play, Hamlet asks himself 'To be, or not to be?', or 'To exist (should I continue living), or not to exist (should I kill myself)?'.

So your sentence becomes 'To comprehend what **exists**, this is the task of philosophy, because what **exists**, is reason'. Or, to rephrase it 'The task of philosophy is to comprehend what exists, because what exists is reason'. I'm no philosopher, so I don't know what that actually *means*, but it's very like Descartes' famous saying 'I think, therefore I am'.

Answer (score -1):

IMO “what is” here represents a philosophical issue, that is, checking [definition](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=j2qEU4LlKaWN4gTP9YGwDA#q=define+reason) #2 of reason: the power of the mind to think, understand, and form judgements logically, would result that **what is** is a matter of existentialism, of being and reasoning, sort of ”I think therefore I am”.

In this context **what is** is not a question, it is a statement: **what is is reason** that is the capacity of thinking.